# gtk_window_set_deletable doesnot remove the Close button (X) from the main window

Tags: c, gtk

Is it possible in GTK+3.0 to remove the close button from the main window (the very first window that is created).
I used `gtk_window_set_deletable(GTK_WINDOW(wmain), FALSE)`, before calling `gtk_window_show(wmain)` but that didn't work. What needs to be corrected?

Comment: What system (window manager, desktop, etc.) are you using? Even though you call `gtk_widget_show()` after `gtk_window_set_deletable()`, the documentation still says there is no guarantee that will actually work (only that doing so increases the chances that it will)... On the other hand, it could be a bug in your window manager or in GTK+.

Comment: I am using raspberry pi's raspbian & i also tried it on ubuntu. But i both the cases, the close button appears on the window.

Answer (score 2):

You can easily do that in Glade. Just select your Window and disable the flag *deletable*, but even through the code: `gtk_window_set_deletable(GTK_WINDOW(window), FALSE)` - if it doesn't work probably you have any other problem in your code. That should work (tested on Gnome Shell 3.12).

Comment: _if it doesn't work probably you have any other problem in your code_
are there any most probable/usual mistakes?

Comment: Did you test setting *deletable* in Window's glade file? Create simple application that just load the window from GtkBuilder.

Comment: _if it doesn't work probably you have any other problem in your code_ -- that's a bold statement: Nothing guarantees that this actually removes the close button: 'deletable' is just a hint that the window manager may decide to disregard.

Answer (score 2):

This feature depends on your window manager as mentioned [here](https://developer.gnome.org/gtk3/stable/GtkWindow.html), ***Some window managers allow GTK+ to disable this button.***

> gtk_window_set_deletable ()
>
> ```
> void
> gtk_window_set_deletable (GtkWindow *window,
>                           gboolean setting);
> ```
>
> By default, windows have a close button in the window frame. Some window
>   managers allow GTK+ to disable this button. If you set the
>   deletable property to FALSE using this function, GTK+ will do its best
>   to convince the window manager not to show a close button. Depending
>   on the system, this function may not have any effect when called on a
>   window that is already visible, so you should call it before calling
>   gtk_widget_show().
>       On Windows, this function always works, since there’s no window manager policy involved.
>   Parameters
>   window
>   a GtkWindow
>
> setting
>   TRUE to decorate the window as deletable
>
> Since: 2.10